# PHP authentication page

Tags: php, windows

trying to use popular example to authenticate a user on my php web page. my site is hosted on public windows .net server (yes... PHP is also running) I ran phpinfo to see server setup, looks like `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is allowed, I did read about windows PHP servers sometimes require CGI and not module. I keep getting the login prompt even after entering user/password combo, never get past that?

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

[image: phpinfo]

Comment: Could you add a link to the "popular example" in question?

Comment: the code is provided...

Comment: here is link: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: @BarclayVision Did you read all comments and check all suggested fixes from them?

Comment: really? I here asking because the example is not working for me, I'm sure I'm missing something, YES I have tried fixes... since I don't control the server, most are not something I can adjust.

Comment: Why you dont make a form login with $_SESSION ?

Comment: I wanted to take advantage of the built in server features.

Answer (score 1):

PHP on IIS not receiving Username and Password is a common scenario, that can easily be worked around: Use the `Authorization` header.

This is just from memory, consider it a starting point

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {
    $auth=explode(' ',$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);
    if ((strtoupper($auth[0])=='BASIC') || (sizeof($auth)==2)) {
      $auth=@base64_decode($auth[1]);
      if ($auth) {
        $auth=explode(':',$auth,2);
        if (sizeof($auth)==2) {
          $_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE']='Basic';
          $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']=$auth[0];
          $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']=$auth[1];
        }
      }
    }
  }
//Now proceed as normal
```

Comment: getting error on  `$auth=@base64_decode($auth[1])` fixed $$ to ||

Comment: not sure if this is an issue or not but phpinfo shows _SERVER["AUTH_TYPE"] no value
_SERVER["AUTH_PASSWORD"] no value
_SERVER["AUTH_USER"] ..... NOT PHP_AUTH_USER  ???

Comment: 1. Fixed the `$$` vs. `||` typo, thanks. 2. I did not set `$_SERVER["AUTH_TYPE"]`in the first version, but added that now. 3. Try to echo the values, if they are empty step through the code, and look, where a branch is not taken. No access to a Windows machine right now.

Comment: At this point `$auth` is a string - it evaluates to true, if it is not empty.

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow in the office - there I have access to a last  windows server.

Comment: I just looked at it again - The `;` in the line `$auth=@base64_decode($auth[1])` was missing, now it works for me on a Windows VM.

Comment: it appears that the only choice I may have is @Jose recommendation to use $_SESSION. The web hosting site I'm using is primarily .net and the PHP doesn't support PHP_AUTH_USER or PW it is an IIS6 server.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you try a more basic method and add a session variable when you logged in for ex

when you login

```
$_SESSION['logged']="true";
```

on your page

```
if($_SESSION['logged'] == "true" )
{
//load your page
}else{
//redirect him/her to somewhere
```

and in your logout

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

Comment: I can't see anything in this answer, that has even the slightest relevance to the question asked ...